# HTML Table, vertical scroll of a table body prevents horizontal scrolling of a wrapper div

Tags: html, css

I was trying to build a simple fixed-width html table, with a scrollable body. On mobiles, I wanted it to preserve the width and to overflow with scrolling.

Here's the bin http://output.jsbin.com/hefuzeleza *(open it on mobile phone or tablet, in a browser simulation it works fine)*.

Anyway the code I have looks like this:

```
div.wrapper // width: 1060px; overflow-x: auto
  table
    thead
    tbody // height: 300px; overflow-y: auto;
```

My intent is pretty staightforward, the table should be scrollable in both axes. It works on desktop just like that. But on mobile it doesn't allow the horizontall scroll by dragging on the table body (where overflow-x is set).

I'm assuming the problem is that I cannot move the body horizontally, because the vertical scroll exist and the "touch" mobile event doesn't propagates any further (can't reach the wrapper with X scroll).

I've tried putting z-indexes and changing `overflow-y/x` to `unset` on elements. No result so far, I wonder if there's any other workarounds.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following css line to your div that needs horizontal scroll:

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

I tested on Android and it works. On iOS it's not working. The above setting should do the trick.

Comment: Glad I was able to help.